# How to enter a carriage return in an Excel file

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

How do you enter a **carriage return** or `CHAR(13)` in a worksheet cell *manually* ? I'm not talking about a **line feed** or `CHAR(10)`.

I've seen this in a file and the carriage return had a very weird effect on the cell contents, but I can't reproduce it manually.

**UPDATE**

There are very good answers about how to enter a **line feed** in an Excel worksheet cell, and actually one of them gave me an idea how to achieve what I wanted in the first place:

```
=A1&CHAR(13)&A2 'Then copy cell + paste values only back again.
```

I'll accept the one that updates their content to reflect this. However, it'd be nice to know whether there's an equivalent of <kbd>Alt + Return</kbd> to type a carriage return.

Comment: Another thing that doesn't work, at least in Excel 2013 on Windows: pasting the CR character. Excel (or perhaps Windows) turns the CR into an LF.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found [here](http://www.officearticles.com/excel/carriage_return_within_a_cell_in_microsoft_excel.htm):

**Method 1 - Cell Wrapping**

Often you only need to set the cell to wrap text, and you can set the width of the cell to whatever is desired. Choose Format Cells, Alignment tab, and check Wrap text.

[image]

The result is:

[image]

**Method 2 - Insert a Return**

This one's a no-brainer. Just type the first line, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type the second line. The result is virtually the same as above, however, if you copy and paste this to Word, for instance, you'll end up with a line break. Or if you export to CSV or other text format, you may get unexpected results.

[image]

The result will be:

[image]

**Method 3 - Using a Formula**

To use this, you must have wrap text selected. Here's a sample formula:

```
=A1 & char(13) & A2
```

Then copy the cell and paste the values only back again.

The results, again, are the same as above. However, if you forget to wrap text on the cell, you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: In method 3 he does &char(10)& which is a line feed char(13) is a carriage return which is what's specified in the question see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_characters

Comment: Please note that the only correct answer is **Method 3 - Using a formula** as indicated in the original question.

Comment: As per [my test (image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JktA0.png), Methods 1 and 2 are just plain wrong. Method 1 inserts no line break characters of any kind. Method 2 inserts a linefeed (character 10), which is explicitly not what the question asks for. Even Method 3 is still slightly wrong: the picture still incorrectly shows `CHAR(10)`; and, in at least my Excel 2013, the carriage return doesn't cause the text to wrap, so whether Wrap Text is turned on is immaterial and so should be omitted from the instructions. Please see/edit my CW instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP's edit to the original question, use a formula that uses concatenation and ASCII character 13. Copy it and paste it, values-only, over itself.

Sample formula:

```
="start of text"&CHAR(13)&"continuation of text"
```

or

```
=A1&CHAR(13)&A2
```