# How does one insert a newline character into a cell of an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

How does one insert a newline character into a cell of an Excel spreadsheet?

Up until now I have been copying and pasting the newline from a spreadsheet that already has one.

I am using Office 2003 but I hope that the solution will not be version specific.

But there must be a 'proper' way to do it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/46128/how-to-enter-a-carriage-return-in-an-excel-file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OS it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative when you need to make a global change of say "." to a newline open the Find and Replace dialog enter "." in the "Find what" box and in "Replace with"  press Alt+0010 and click "Replace All"