# Enter "return" in excel?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, office-for-mac

It took me a while to find out how to do [it on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/46128/how-to-enter-a-carriage-return-in-an-excel-file). Now, how do I do the same in Mac?

What's the equivalent for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for Excel on Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out:

<kbd>command</kbd>+
<kbd>option</kbd>+
<kbd>enter</kbd>