# Excel - 'Concatenate' columns with Alt + Enter

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

I am trying to combine three cells into one, with `Alt + Enter` or `Char(10)` separating each value. When I use a simple Excel formula `=B2 & Char(10) & C2 & Char(10) & D2` and wrap the text of the destination cell, everything seems normal.  The actual cell value is a string of `B2`, `C2`, and `D2` run together.  Is there actually a way to have the value appear as if I manually entered `First Value` `Alt + Enter` `Second Value` `Alt + Enter` `Third Value`?

Comment: Sorry, but it's a little unclear what you're asking for. Do you want it to show that way without turning on Word Wrap? Or do you want it not to show up as a formula in the formula bar? Or something else?

Comment: If you want space between the entries, just add `& " " &` to your formula

Comment: Alt+Enter produces an in-cell line break. I'm guessing that OP wants to concatenate values but separate them using such an in-cell line break. I don't know how to create an in-cell line break in a formula, otherwise I'd have posted an answer.

Comment: @CJK:  The formula you posted works for me.  However, have you turned on Word Wrap in the formula cell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enter a carriage return in an Excel file](http://superuser.com/questions/46128/how-to-enter-a-carriage-return-in-an-excel-file)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  With Word Wrap it will look the same, but it wasn't acting the same when I was trying to reference it (I could have incorrectly referenced the formula).  I will probably end up either using `PasteSpecialValues` or just leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!

Once you have entered the formula and see the displayed value looks O.K., copy the cell and PasteSpecialValues back into the cell.

The formula will be gone and the contents will appear to have been entered manually!

Or you may also paste special values with source formatting and you get the desired results

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work using CHAR(13) instead of CHAR(10):

=CONCATENATE(A9&CHAR(13),A11&CHAR(13),A13)